# 2048 algorithm for merging

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Ok, here's a question my friend just sent me, ive mastered it to some extent, but am failing, so, please help a little:

> Your target is to merge these blocks in such a way that one bigger number is formed. The merging takes place as follows : Two blocks of value 2 will make one block of value 4, then two block of value 4 will make one block of value 8 and so on. At any step, after merging, if there is a block left, then that block is automatically upgraded to next higher value. You need to find out the numbers of block merges required to get largest number possible.
>
> **Aim: Find the number of block merges required to get largest number possible**

As a clue, my friend also told me that if the number of 2 blocks given are 5, in that case, the answer is 4 as, 5 blocks of 2s will make 2 blocks of 4 and one block of 2 will be upgraded to 4. Now 2 blocks of 4 will make one block 8 and one block of 4 will be upgraded to 8. Finally 2 blocks of 8 will make one block of 16 (which is the largest number possible).
Hence number of merges required are: 2 + 1 + 1 = 4

FInding the algorithm to master seems highly impossible to me...

Comment: Why was this downvoted ???

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. But anyone who has played 2048 knows that not all the rules of the game have been explained here, so the question is underspecified to a significant degree. The upgrade rule makes it sound like this is a non-standard variant of the game. What do you mean by "there is a block left"? There is always at least a single block left. What if there is a 2048 and a 2 remaining? Will the 2 first get upgraded to 4, then 8, then...?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ive added an explanation, see if it helps

Comment: Can no one help me ?????

Comment: It took 350 years to prove Fermat's Last Theorem, and you're freaking out because you've had to wait 28 minutes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Everyone except Fermat had to wait that long, anyway~

Answer (score 0):

Given an initial $N$ blocks, let $z$ be the largest integer such that $2^z \le N$.  Any number of blocks beyond a power of 2 cannot be used to increase the maximum achievable tile-value.

Therefore $z = \lfloor \log_2 (N) \rfloor$.

Now if the number of merges that takes place is $M$, then work out the first few values:

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c} N & z & M \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 \dots 3 & 1 & 1 \\
4 \dots 7 & 2 & 1 + 2 = 3 \\
8 \dots 15 & 3 & 1 + 2 + 4 = 7 \\
16 \dots 31 & 4 & 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}$$

Try to work out the pattern, it helps to look at the value of $M+1$.